# Where is the cart.php template called in woocommerce template?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I need to modify the cart template in my woocommerce theme, I change the cart.php as I desire from my design but I need to change the header, and remove the widgets positions fro this page, And I cant find the place where the car.php file is called

Comment: WordPress pages consists of several different sections, header, content, footer and sidebar. The cart.php only sets the content section. The other sections are standard WordPress sections and are set by the header, footer and sidebar templates.Let me know if this hint isn't enough.

Comment: @MagentaCuda so you say that the cart.php is loaded like other page content? and if not assigned template, use the default page.php? let me try

Comment: There is a page 'Cart' which you can view in the page editor - Dashboard -> All Pages. If you do this you will see that the content of this page is the shortcode [woocommerce_cart]. This shortcode renders the cart.

Comment: The shortcode processing will eventually call wc_get_template( 'cart/cart.php' ).

Comment: @MagentaCuda I put this in the page.php and its works for me    ```if (!is_cart()) the_content()``` and the cart is not show, so somehow by default cart.php is inserted in page.php thanks for your hint

Comment: 'so somehow by default cart.php is inserted in page.php' - my previous comments tried to explain this, do I need to explain further?

Comment: @MagentaCuda no, no thanks for your help, now I cant modify the theme as I Hish. Put your hints as an answer to give you the votes ;)

Comment: I am too lazy to write this up carefully, just happy that I could help.